# Broke something on MSI GF63 Motherboard

Tags: laptop-repair, repair

I broke a part on an MSI GF63 motherboard. It seems to be soldered on to the motherboard and wouldn't come out so when I applied a little pressure the plastic cover broke.

The ribbon cable is still attached and intact.

If it's removable help me identify the part so I can find a replacement if need be.

What's the function of the part.

[image: pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

[image: Pic 3]

Comment: You broke the ribbon connector or the ribbon cable? Your screenshots don’t show anything to identify either the PCB kr the cable itself. You should take it to a shop so they can identify what exactly broke so you can order a replacement

Comment: It looks like you've only broken the plastic housing, not the connector itself.

Comment: Please describe the damage? Is anything not working? Is the ribbon cable connected or lose? Written description is vital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That white plastic cover is part of the part itself.
It is normally the entire connector that needs replacing.
You can't just buy a new cover.

Having said that...
If you can find a replacement foil-contact connector of exactly the same brand/type/model that you broke, you may be able to carefully take the cover off and transplanting that to the broken connector.

And it is possible you managed to damage the foil-cable itself.
They are quite fragile.

If the computer still works as it is now, just don't do anything to it.
In that case you were very lucky.
Leave it be.

Comment: Thanks. The PC is working.